# Setting a value by a friend function which is a member function of another class

Tags: c++, friend

`setwidth()` is a member function of class `Box` and it is also a friend function of class `Sbox` which is setting the values of members `width` of both classes.

The value of `width` of the class `Sbox` is not setting/coming out properly.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sbox;

class Box{
    private:
        double width;
    public:
        friend void printwidth(Box box);
        void setwidth(Sbox sbox, double wid);
};

class Sbox {
    private:
        double width;
    public:
        friend void Box::setwidth(Sbox sbox, double wid);
        void printwidth() {
            cout << "the width of small box: " << width; //this value is coming wrong
        }
};

void Box::setwidth(Sbox sbox, double wid) {
    width = wid;
    sbox.width = wid;
}

void printwidth(Box box) {
    cout << "width of the box: " << box.width << endl;
}

int main() {
    Box box;
    Sbox sbox;
    box.setwidth(sbox, 10.77);
    printwidth(box);
    sbox.printwidth();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the Sbox in by reference. Add the ampersand to these three lines.

`void setwidth(Sbox& sbox,double wid);`

`friend void Box::setwidth(Sbox& sbox,double wid);`

`void Box::setwidth(Sbox& sbox,double wid)`

You were passing your `sbox` in by value, which means that a copy is made for use inside `setwidth`. Your code then changes the width on that copy of `sbox`, but the copy is then destroyed at the end of `setwidth`, and the original `sbox` outside the function remains unchanged.

Adding the `&` means that the `Sbox` argument is passed by reference, which means that a copy is never made, and so the `sbox` inside `setwidth` is the same object as the one outside.

Have a read here: [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)